# undefined reference to `llist_init(LinkedList*)'

Tags: c++

I got a short question. I'm getting this error

```
undefined reference to `llist_init(LinkedList*)'
```

my Stack.cpp includes

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
```

LinkedList.h has a init function

```
 void llist_init(LinkedList * list);
```

I can't understand why it's telling me "undefined" since I include LinkedList.h and LinkedList.h has a llist_init function. help!

Comment: you need to show code. Please read about [mcve] and provide one

Comment: A declaration is not a definition.